# Saber o nome do objeto em JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tenho um JSON e preciso saber o nome do meu objeto e os valores que ele tem, por exemplo:

```
    {"Pessoas" :
          [ 
           {"Nome": "Welson Play", "Idade":19}, 
           {"Nome": "Stephanie", "Idade":15},
           {"Nome": "João Pedro", "Idade":17}
          ] 
    }
```

Precisava pegar no código o nome `Pessoas` e as valores que cada pessoa tem, mas isso sem saber o nome, por exemplo, poderia ser `Animais`, `Carros`. Isso devido que minha tabela no `BD` as colunas podem variar, ou seja, navegar pelo `JSON`.

Comment: Você quer a solução em PHP? Acho que respondi errado em javascript. =(

Comment: Oi @Fernando obrigado por responder, pode ser em PHP tbm, preciso analisar os codigos e ver qual eu vou usar, se puder me ajudar com o PHP eu agradeço

Comment: Ok! Vou remover minha resposta, PHP não muito a minha, hehe. E acho que o Sergio já respondeu bem em PHP. Não me atentei as tags antes de responder, desculpe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar um [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) para iterar esse objeto.

Por exemplo:

```
$jsonstring = '{"Pessoas" :
      [ 
       {"Nome": "Welson Play", "Idade":19}, 
       {"Nome": "Stephanie", "Idade":15},
       {"Nome": "João Pedro", "Idade":17}
      ] 
}';

$obj = json_decode($jsonstring);

foreach($obj as $chave => $array) {
    echo $chave;    // dá "Pessoas"
    // fazer aqui o que fôr preciso com a array $array
}
```

Exemplo: https://ideone.com/u6kmv8

Para ler os objetos objetos filhos, (`nome`, `idade` ....) é preciso continuar a iterar. No exemplo em cima pode iterar-se a array e depois as chaves/valor de cada objeto.

Na prática é preciso mais dois loops:

```
foreach($obj as $chave => $array) {
    foreach($array as $index => $pessoa) {
        foreach($pessoa as $dado => $valor) {
            // neste nível estás dentro de cada objeto `{"Nome": "João Pedro", "Idade":17}`
```

Comment: Você respondeu primeiro... kkkk

Comment: @Sergio, como faria para eu ler os objetos filhos, (nome, idade ....)?

Comment: @Furlan juntei mais info à resposta. Se não conseguires implementar preciso de um exemplo concreto de como queres usar esses valores dentro do objeto de cada pessoa.

Comment: @Sergio, para iterar realmente por todos os filhos acho mais interessante utilizar recursividade, mas realmente depende de como o AP pretende utilizar isto. Mas de modo geral e abrangente recursividade é a solução.

Comment: @Fernando concordo. A pergunta é pouco clara no que se quer fazer com os dados, daí ter usado 3 foreach iguais já a abrir porta para ser mais DRY/recursivo.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, @Sergio obrigado pelo seu tempo, mais uma vez caso encerrado!

Comment: @Sergio, tem como eu pegar a característica do objeto sem eu saber, exemplo, meu objeto tem 3 caracteristicas: nome, idade, sexo. Mas pode variar esses 3, ai ali no 3ª foreach eu colocar dinamicamente, tem como?